# Save submitted form values as cookie

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, session, session-cookies

Right now I am storing session variables with `jQuery` like:

```
$("form#sessie_datum").change(function() {
 var str = $("form#sessie_datum").serialize();
 $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'http://URL.com/datum.php',
           data: $("form#sessie_datum").serialize(),
           dataType: 'text',
           success: function() {
           alert('Variables has been stored in the session');
           },
 });
 return false;
});
```

In my `datum.php` file I get the submitted values by name,
this is my `form`:

```
<form id="sessie_datum">
<input type="text" class="aantal_alpincenter" name="personen_aantal" value="">
<input type="text" id="datepicker2" placeholder="Click to choose a date" name="wapbk_hidden_date" value="">
<div id="datepicker"></div>
</form>
```

`datum.php` beneath here

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION["chosen_date"] = $_POST['wapbk_hidden_date'];
$_SESSION["personen"] = $_POST['personen_aantal'];

?>
```

In every `php` file I can get the session variables like:

```
session_start();
$date = htmlentities($_SESSION["chosen_date"]);
```

Instead of using `session_start();` I want to use `cookies` so I can prevent a conflict with my `caching` plugin and let the variables been stored on the user their computer for 1 day for example. Anyone knows how to do this with `cookies`?

Comment: you are doing it in sessions instead of cookies!

Comment: Yeah I know but I want to set cookies of the variables which has been submitted

Comment: Why not use transients?

Comment: What are transients? With `WP Rocket` I can exclude `cookies` so that is the main reason I want to set `cookies`

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API I'd use transient rather than storing data in a cookie.

Comment: use something like the `setcookie()` function if you want to define a cookie: https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_http_setcookie.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save cookies with [setcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function.

Simply saving all POST data to cookies with PHP would be something like that:

```
<?php 
// Check if request method is post
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // If you wanna modify key text, you may do so like this:
    switch ($key) {
      case 'wapbk_hidden_date':
        $cookie_key = 'chosen_date';
        break;

      case 'personen_aantal':
        $cookie_key = 'personen';
        break;

      default:
        $cookie_key = $key;
        break;
    }

    // Saves cookie for 1 day on this domain
    setcookie($cookie_key, $value, time()+3600*24, "/");
  }
}
```

And then, when you want to use your cookie, get it with global variable [$_COOKIE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php):

```
$date = htmlentities($_COOKIE['chosen_date']);
```

Comment: Do I need place this code in my functions.php or datum.php?

Comment: @PelHout URL of your AJAX POST request, so in your case, yes, datum.php